# Missing system injecting dependencies using vanilla php

Tags: php, containers

I'm trying to get my app working, Its a vanilla php, I have 2 services with one dependent on other. I'm running service from the bootstrap, which requires simple SplClassLoader.

The directory structure (Slightly simplified):

```
 -src
    -logic
       -Service
          -CustomService.php
          -DataProviderService.php
       -SplClassLoader.php
 -test
    -bootstrap.php
```

Bootstrap:

```
<?php
require __DIR__  . '/../src/SplClassLoader.php';

$oClassLoader = new \SplClassLoader('logic', __DIR__ . '/../src');
$oClassLoader->register();
$service = new logic\Service\CustomService;
$service->execute();
```

SplClassLoader:

```
<?php

/**
 * SplClassLoader implementation that implements the technical interoperability
 * standards for PHP 5.3 namespaces and class names.
 *
 * http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/final-proposal
 *
 *     // Example which loads classes for the Doctrine Common package in the
 *     // Doctrine\Common namespace.
 *     $classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', '/path/to/doctrine');
 *     $classLoader->register();
 *
 * @author Jonathan H. Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 * @author Roman S. Borschel <roman@code-factory.org>
 * @author Matthew Weier O'Phinney <matthew@zend.com>
 * @author Kris Wallsmith <kris.wallsmith@gmail.com>
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@symfony-project.org>
 */
class SplClassLoader
{
    private $_fileExtension = '.php';
    private $_namespace;
    private $_includePath;
    private $_namespaceSeparator = '\\';

    /**
     * Creates a new <tt>SplClassLoader</tt> that loads classes of the
     * specified namespace.
     *
     * @param string $ns The namespace to use.
     */
    public function __construct($ns = null, $includePath = null)
    {
        $this->_namespace = $ns;
        $this->_includePath = $includePath;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the namespace separator used by classes in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @param string $sep The separator to use.
     */
    public function setNamespaceSeparator($sep)
    {
        $this->_namespaceSeparator = $sep;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the namespace seperator used by classes in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getNamespaceSeparator()
    {
        return $this->_namespaceSeparator;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the base include path for all class files in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @param string $includePath
     */
    public function setIncludePath($includePath)
    {
        $this->_includePath = $includePath;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the base include path for all class files in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @return string $includePath
     */
    public function getIncludePath()
    {
        return $this->_includePath;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file extension of class files in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @param string $fileExtension
     */
    public function setFileExtension($fileExtension)
    {
        $this->_fileExtension = $fileExtension;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file extension of class files in the namespace of this class loader.
     *
     * @return string $fileExtension
     */
    public function getFileExtension()
    {
        return $this->_fileExtension;
    }

    /**
     * Installs this class loader on the SPL autoload stack.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Uninstalls this class loader from the SPL autoloader stack.
     */
    public function unregister()
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Loads the given class or interface.
     *
     * @param string $className The name of the class to load.
     * @return void
     */
    public function loadClass($className)
    {
        if (null === $this->_namespace || $this->_namespace.$this->_namespaceSeparator === substr($className, 0, strlen($this->_namespace.$this->_namespaceSeparator))) {
            $fileName = '';
            $namespace = '';
            if (false !== ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, $this->_namespaceSeparator))) {
                $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
                $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
                $fileName = str_replace($this->_namespaceSeparator, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            }
            $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . $this->_fileExtension;
            require ($this->_includePath !== null ? $this->_includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '') . $fileName;
        }
    }
}
```

So yeah, Im running php `php bootstrap.php` and getting error that too few arguments passed into contructor. How to make bootstrap load dependency injections? How I should make it work? Can I use some kind of service container of phpunit maybe? Its a clue I have been given. No idea if I did explain problem well enough, but hope I did! :)

Error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function logic\Service\CustomService::execute(), 0 passed in /.../test/bootstrap.php on line 12 and exactly 1 expected in /.../Service/CustomService.php:23
    Stack trace:
    #0 /.../test/bootstrap.php(12): logic\Service\CustomService->execute()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in /.../logic/Service/CustomService.php on line 23
```

Comment: Is your objective to learn how autoloaders work, or simply to get a functional autoloader to continue with your project? The defactor standard is to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: `and getting error that too few arguments passed into contructor` please include error messages _verbatim_ in the question - don't paraphrase them.

Comment: Hmm well my goal is to get this working but would like to learn how autoloaders do work aswell, use composer... mind explaining, I must admit Im first time doing something so 'deep', trying to config it all from the low lvl

Comment: Sure, what was unclear about the docs I already linked to? line 12 (the error message) is apparently `$service->execute();` - which indicates the autoloader works, because it found the class. The error message relates to how you are calling this (not in the question) class method, is different from the error message previously mentioned `getting error that too few arguments passed into contructor`, and has no bearing on the question asked. Please clarify your question.